# Alternative writing method to create DOM elements and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

If  I want to append a button with my pic to the document, I would write:

```
$('#story_pages').append('<div><button value="'+window_value+'" onclick="reload_to_canvas(this.value)" > <img id= "w'+window_value+'", src="../pic/white_img.png", width="110px", height="110px"/> </button></div>');
```

It's too long and hard to debug. But how can I create an img tag, then wrapping it with a button tag and div tag...

Please suggest any clear and simple method with jQuery's help.

**UPDATE**:
story_pages is the jQuery UI dialog's id. I don't know if it affects or not.

**UPDATE:**
I found the problem. I want the image shown above on the button instead of a button and a image.

The script you give me will result this:

```
<div>
<button value="1"></button>
<img ......./>
</div>
```

The img tag has to be wrapped by button tag like:

```
<button>
    <img.../>
</button>
```

So the image will **attach** on the button.

Comment: How about [jQuery.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) ?

Comment: Templates would be great alternative.

Comment: @dfsq    Excuse me, what do you mean? What does the `Templates` refers?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, you guys help me a lot. But sorry, I can only select one answer, although the rest are all correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with ). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as explained above. But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these elements.

try this

```
  var div=$('<div>'); // creates new div element

  //updated here
  var img = $('<img />') .attr({   // create new img elementand adds the mentioned attr
                   id:'w'+window_value , 
                   src:"../pic/white_img.png",
                   width:"110px", 
                   height:"110px"});

  var button= $('<button/>',  //creates new button
  {   
    value: window_value,  //add text to button
    click: function(){ reload_to_canvas(this.value)} //and the click event
  }).html(img);   /// and <-- here... pushed the created img to buttons html


 div.append(button); //append button ,img to div
 $('#story_pages').append(div);   //finally appends div to the selector
```

[updated example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/4rB3y/2/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to add a value on the button `screen`. What I want is that as the user presses the button, it will pass the value to the function reload_to_canvas(`value`). Thank you. 
BTW: why can we write :var div=$('<div>');
Does this instrument create a div? I want to know about the syntax.
Thanks again.

Comment: ok change `text` to `value` and that should do..updated...anyways `var div=$('<div>');` .. this creates a new div element..its like calling `document.createElement('div')`; you can have a look to this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: Uh... It's weird, why the image's size is incorrect. It is not shown 110 by 110.

Comment: Uh... It's embarrassing. It still can't work. The img's size is incorrect. Did you test the code?

Comment: yes.. did u check the example fiddle above....i inspected the element and it is showing the right width and height

Comment: I use Chromium console to execute the script. Btw: story_pages is the jQuery UI dialog's id. I don't know if it affects or not.

Comment: that should not effect if you hardcoded the img width and height.. i.e   110px

Comment: `I want the image shown above on the button instead of a button and a image.` this is done.. check my answer and fiddle

Comment: Well, that's right! What's the error before? And what did you add so that it works right, hoping you can highlight it. Thank you!

Comment: Well... Sorry. Can you tell me how to avoid the new image button grows in a vertical direction. I want the new one to grow horizontally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26085/discussion-between-stallman-and-bipen)

Comment: No. It can't work even if I set the width and height to `20px`. Is there any possible that the div tag influences the result?

Comment: I didn't... Then is there any possible that I append these div tag to a jQueryUI dialog?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var $button = $('<button>', {
  value: window_value,
  click: function() { reload_to_canvas(this.value); }
});

var $img = $('<img>', {
  id : 'w'+ window_value,
  src: '../pic/white_img.png'
})
.css({ height: '100px', width: '100px'});

$('#story_pages').append($('<div>').append($button, $img));
```

Comment: Sorry, can you give me some explanation about your syntax? Official document is also available. Because it's hard for me to understand it.

Comment: The image's width and height are not shown as expected values.

Comment: `width` and `height` methods take numbers not strings, but it sets the values in pixels.

Comment: No, I don't know why it still can't work. The img's size is not 110 *110.

Comment: Change to: `.append($('<div>').append($button.append($img)))`. Best advice is to try understanding the problem and the answers is good practice, it's how you actually learn stuff.

Comment: Well... Sorry. Can you tell me how to avoid the new `image button` grows in a vertical direction. I want the new one to grow horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#story_pages').append(
    $('<div>').append(
        $('<button>', {
            value : window_value
        }).click(function() {
            reload_to_canvas(this.value);
        }).append(
            $('<img>', {
                id : 'w' + window_value,
                src : '../pic/white_img.png'
            }).width(110)
              .height(110)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I changed it, but not sure it works properly, I just wanted to show the main idea of not using variables for elements, but directly appending them. This way you end up with a more readable code.